# Curl Command returns empty from URL

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script that will install the pre-requisites for installing Docker Desktop on Pop!_OS and once those are satisfied, it will install the latest version of Docker Desktop. More of an exercise in learning shell scripting than anything.

**Attempt 1**

```
#!/bin/bash

# get the latest version number
latest_version=$(curl -s https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/ | grep -oP '(?<=#)[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?' | head -n 1)
printf "$latest_version"
```

**this prints nothing to the screen.**

**Attempt 2**

```
#!/bin/bash

# get the latest version number
version=$(curl -s https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/ \
| grep -oE '/desktop/release-notes/#[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' \
| grep -oE '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' \
| sort -rn \
| head -n 1)

# check if version number is empty
if [ -z "$version" ]; then
    echo "Unable to retrieve the latest version number."
    exit 1
fi
```

**This prints "unable to retrieve the latest version number" to the console.**

So, is this a limitation of curl or is the regex just wrong?

Comment: Your question is about curl and everything else is just noise. You should eliminate everything in your question that is not curl related. But, then, your question is off topic here as not programming related and you should delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or https://superuser.com/

Comment: That is somewhat of a hostile answer. I posted the full code so that everyone can have context because each time I use this site, pretty much the first thing I am asked is to post the full code. I have removed the fluff and posted only the necessary code then.

Comment: You might have better success using tools that are better suited for parsing html.  (Python with BeautifulSoup, for example).  You might  also try XSLT or XPATH for munging html. That said, the following may work for you in the short term: `curl -s https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/ | egrep '<h2 id="[0-9]+">' | xmllint --html --xpath '//h2/text()' - | sort -t. -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n | tail -n 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command gets the list of all versions

```
curl -s https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/ | grep -oP '<h2 id=.*>\K.*(?=<.*)'
```

If you want the most recent version, append `| head -n 1` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You might be hitting what I encountered trying to reproduce your issue.

If I open the Release page in my browser, then "**save page as**", then open the html page using a text editor, the target line is being displayed as

```
<h2 id="4170">4.17.0<a href="#4170" class="anchorLink">{image}</a></h2>
```

Your logic seems to be attempting to parse for that line format.

**SIMPLIFYING** (**to make sure we are in the right ballpark with the results**), when I try the modified command

```
curl -s https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/ | grep 'href="#'
```

there are *no lines of the expected format reported*.  That is suggesting that something is dynamically pushing the additional details which you were hoping to capture.

HOWEVER, if I use the firefox plugin "**Download Serialized DOM**" to save the fully "re-constituted" web page to disk, the text editor now locates the desired pattern.

SO, you need to use a method similar to that.

ALSO, I suggest you had a "**grep 'anchorLink'" before** your number matching, to eliminate spurious numeric references.

LASTLY, you need to be **more specific** with the sort routine to get the order you really want:

```
sort -t. -k 1,1nr -k 2,2nr -k 3,3nr
```